# Data modelling: techniques to handle lots of data?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, database-design, data-modeling

So I have a relatively small website with growing amounts of data - the fastest growing table is pageviews, as we do all our analytics ourselves. The website is made using VB.Net, SQL Server 2008 and jQuery. I am limited to .net 2.5.

I currently handle all the data and validation using objects with a list of attributes. Each attribute is of a specific datatype and has a validation function when a new value is given to it. If the data does not validate then it won't even get as far as updating the database and feeds back an error to the user. Currently I have "Manager" classes and "Item" classes - Items are managed by a particular Manager class, for example Users are managed by the UserManager, so to get all the users I just have to call UserManager.Items. These Manager classes are stored in the cache and are created as needed - but once a Manager class is referenced it creates **all** of the Items within it. This is getting rather slow now, as the company is growing fast. It takes 2 - 3 seconds to load the first page (the page which makes most first-time requests to data) but I am not happy with this time. After that it is nearly instant.

Now the way I see it I have 3 options to speed the website up:

- Keep it as it is, but try to make it more efficient through other techniques;
- Change to creating all these objects on every page load, in the hope that it is simply so slow because I am using the cache to store a fair amount of data (about 10 MB or so at least);
- Forgetting using object oriented techniques and just use straight SQL queries and loop through records.

Does anyone have any recommendations on which approach I should use? If I have missed any options then please suggest them.

Thank you.

Regards,

Richard

Comment: I dont understand `These Manager classes are stored in the cache and are created as needed`. If you are storing them in cache, they shouldn't need to be reloaded on first page. Cache is application- and session-wide and will only be cleared f.e. if all sessions are timed out. Or have you specified a cachepolicy?

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't explain that bit very well. I am aware that the cache is shared between all users - but basically there is some problem on the server where it recycles the application after about 5 minutes - so after about 5 mins of inactivity the cache is emptied so the next pageview (by anyone) will reload all the data for any requested managers. I can't locate the source of the recycling issue - it is on my long to-do list, however!

Comment: I suggest you move it to the top of your list! Try the event log, also check that the application is not simply configured to restart every 5 minutes...

Answer (score 1):

I think that for your website you can't use the concept "direct access attribute": UserManager.Items.

If you have a growing amount of data you should have an "indirect access attribute" for your manager classes, that would be a method like UserManager.GetItems(). Because the .NET calculates the Proprieties (UserManager.Items) when you create a new instance of the UserManager class...

**Resume:**  remove UserManager.Items attribute and create a method UserManager.GetItems().